# How can i use multiple panels with different layouts for my gui?

Tags: java, user-interface, panel

i have problems with nesting 2 different button panels into my main panel. It worked for me with only one 1 panel. Now with my actual nesting i see the last added panel over my main panel and my first button panel. Additionally the "editButton" i added, is not showing up. I got no errors while compiling. It seems to be that i just made a mistake in the arrangement.
Would be very nice if there are any suggestions. Here is my code snippet:
Thanks in advance!

```
private final String name;
private JLabel catLabel;
private JButton cat1Button;
private JButton cat2Button;
private JButton cat3Button;
private JButton cat4Button;
private JButton editButton;
private JButton deleteButton;
private JButton insertButton;

public JPanel panelMain;
public JPanel panel;
public JPanel panel1;


public ReadwriteQuiz readwrite;

public GUIEdit(String name){

    this.name = name;
    this.setTitle(name);

    this.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    this.setLayout((null));
    this.setSize(400,300);
    this.setLocation(400,150);
    this.setResizable(false);

    panelMain = new JPanel();
    panelMain.setLayout(new BoxLayout(panelMain, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));

    panel = new JPanel();
    panel.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
    panel.setBackground(Color.lightGray);

    panel1 = new JPanel();
    panel1.setLayout(new BoxLayout(panel1, BoxLayout.X_AXIS));
    panel1.setBackground(Color.ORANGE);

    panelMain.add(panel);
    panelMain.add(panel1);

    catLabel= new JLabel("Willkommen zum Quizzeln ! \n Wählen Sie Ihre Kategorie");
    catLabel.setBounds(90,10,260,40);
    panel.add(catLabel);

    cat1Button = new JButton("Kategorie 1");
    cat1Button.setBounds(52,90,120,40);
    panel.add(cat1Button);
    cat1Button.addActionListener((e) -> {
        try {
            readwrite.readFile("kategorie1.txt");
        } catch (FileNotFoundException fileNotFoundException) {
            fileNotFoundException.printStackTrace();
        }
    });

    cat2Button = new JButton("Kategorie 2");
    cat2Button.setBounds(220,90,120,40);
    panel.add(cat2Button);

    cat3Button = new JButton("Kategorie 3");
    cat3Button.setBounds(52,160,120,40);
    panel.add(cat3Button);

    cat4Button = new JButton("Kategorie 4");
    cat4Button.setBounds(220,160,120,40);
    panel.add(cat4Button);

    editButton = new JButton("Frage editieren");
    editButton.setBounds(52,400,120,40);
    panel1.add(editButton);

    this.add(panelMain);
    this.add(panel);
    this.add(panel1);
    this.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
}

@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have one main panel and you have already added the other nested panels to the main panel
so you only add that main panel to the parent panel
but you're adding the main panel ( including the other 2 ) and again adding the 1st panel and again adding the 2nd panel

so

```
this.add(panelMain);
```

should be enough

---

Full class

```
public class app {
    private JTextField textField1;
    private JPanel panel;
    private JLabel label;
    private JLabel catLabel;
    private JButton cat1Button;
    private JButton cat2Button;
    private JButton cat3Button;
    private JButton cat4Button;
    private JButton editButton;
    private JButton deleteButton;
    private JButton insertButton;

    public JPanel panelMain;
    public JPanel panel2;
    public JPanel panel1;

    public app(JFrame frame) {

        panelMain = new JPanel();
        panelMain.setLayout(new BoxLayout(panelMain, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));

        panel2 = new JPanel();
        panel2.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        panel2.setBackground(Color.lightGray);

        panel1 = new JPanel();
        panel1.setLayout(new BoxLayout(panel1, BoxLayout.X_AXIS));
        panel1.setBackground(Color.ORANGE);

        panelMain.add(panel2);
        panelMain.add(panel1);

        catLabel= new JLabel("Willkommen zum Quizzeln ! \n Wählen Sie Ihre Kategorie");
        catLabel.setBounds(90,10,260,40);
        panel2.add(catLabel);

        cat1Button = new JButton("Kategorie 1");
        cat1Button.setBounds(52,90,120,40);
        panel2.add(cat1Button);

        cat2Button = new JButton("Kategorie 2");
        cat2Button.setBounds(220,90,120,40);
        panel2.add(cat2Button);

        cat3Button = new JButton("Kategorie 3");
        cat3Button.setBounds(52,160,120,40);
        panel2.add(cat3Button);

        cat4Button = new JButton("Kategorie 4");
        cat4Button.setBounds(220,160,120,40);
        panel2.add(cat4Button);

        editButton = new JButton("Frage editieren");
        editButton.setBounds(52,400,120,40);
        panel1.add(editButton);
        frame.add(panelMain);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame fram = new JFrame("app");
        new app(fram);
        fram.pack();
        fram.setVisible(true);
        }
    }
```

Comment: alright, yeah that makes sense to me, but unfortunately it doesnt change anything ...
i also put panelMain.add(panel) and panelMain.add(panel1) at the position after adding the buttons

Comment: I just tried it and it worked I guess your view should be like this https://www2.0zz0.com/2020/08/06/22/765528528.png ?

Comment: @JanLi what's `this` referring to?

Comment: this should be referring to the frame/window

Comment: well im not very expert in Java GUI but the only difference I made other than removing the 2 extra adds is changing "this" with the actual frame 
here's my full class I'll edit the answer

Comment: many thanks man, i just changed a bit of my code and got a bit further .

Comment: You should NOT pass the frame in the constructor. The  class should be designed so that the panel can be added to a frame, dialog, window or even another panel.